# Cannot use conditionally use export keyword on Node.JS server when trying to use code shared between server and client?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JS file that contains a bunch of constants and a few primitive functions in a module named *global-namespaces.js*.  I am now trying to upgrade my code on the client side to use `modules` and the `import` statement.  By the way, I know the code below looks awkward but that's because I'm struggling to find a solution still.

On the server side I just use *require()*.  However, I can't seem to find a way to export the needed symbols from `global-namespaces.js` when used in the client side context that doesn't generate a syntax error on the server side.  I can't put the `export` block/keyword in an IF statement because that generates a syntax error.  Here is my current code:

```js
    try {
        g_GlobalNamespaces = new GlobalNamespaces();
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(`${errPrefix}Error occurred during the creation of the global GlobalNamespaces object.`);
        console.info(errPrefix + `err object:`);
        console.dir(err, {depth: null, colors: true});
    }

    // Use this code on both client and server side.  Are we on the server side?
    if (typeof module == 'undefined' || typeof module.exports == 'undefined')
    {
        // No. g_GlobalNamespaces is already in the client side global namespace.
    } else {
        // Yes.  Export the code so it works with require().
        module.exports =
            {
                g_GlobalNamespaces: g_GlobalNamespaces
            }
    }

    //  We export it so it can be used via "import" statements.
    export // THIS STATEMENT GENERATES THE SYNTAX ERROR ON THE SERVER SIDE.
    {
        g_GlobalNamespaces
    }
```

This SO post has no answers:

[How to share code between client and server when using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863035/how-to-share-code-between-client-and-server-when-using-node-js)

And this SO post only handles the client-side only case and doesn't help me with the client and server side sharing issue:

[Conditional export in ES2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583958/conditional-export-in-es2015)

How can I structure *global-namespaces.js* so I can use the code both on the server and the client side?